# What kind of stats I can get from TFS 2013 regarding developers performance?

Tags: git, performance, statistics, bug-reporting

We are using GIT repositories and I'd like to get some statistics related to developers for code, work items, defects/bugs. At the moment I cant find any at all and it seems you have to buy third party integrations tools to get something. It's a bit strange given the money we paid for the MSDN subscription.

Comment: dont know why it got voted down. This is the only thing I found https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647430.aspx. Although that gives you everything , it seems odd there is not an easier way to get simple stats like Teamcity and JIRA. Even in Jira you can use the full API if you want more but you need a person just to do that full time.

Comment: and BTW the link is for a very old version of TFS

Comment: Did you try the TFS reports?

Comment: @ds19 I can find a lot of documentation to create my own reports and probabily if I had a few spare weeks, I could do something fancy. But that's not what I'm asking

Comment: I meant the standard TFS reports: Bug Status, Bug Trends, Remaining Work, Stories Overview and so on.
Can you elaborate what are you missing?

Comment: @ds19 how can you think that remaining work for example is a stats for developer performance? That's just for Agile to know how much is remaining before the end of the sprint! If I have something (just for the sake of explaining to you) like how many time a developer committed to a task and didnt finish in each sprint, then that's a metric I could use to measure my developer performance. I hope you are not the one voting down as you demonstrate to not even understand the question.

Comment: @ds19 Anyway the link I provided (TFS scorecard) is quite good and simple to use and configure. I'm still wondering why Microsoft as usual does thing by halves.. If you look at Visual Studio Online 2015, it has enough of what I'm asking but of course cannot move to the online version!!

Comment: The easiest way of creating your own reports is to use Excel and the TFS Analysis database as data source. (I didn't voted down).
And BTW the updated link for TFS2013 is https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb649552%28v=vs.120%29.aspx or for TFS2015 https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Report/overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can find (free) and nearly ready OOTB is this one

http://tfsscorecard.codeplex.com/